# We can call getView() method on Ext.Component but the sdk doc doesnt show getView() method

Tags: extjs, rally

```
 GridComponent = {

            xtype: 'rallygrid',
            itemId: 'mygrid',
            store: myStore,
            //collapsible: true,
            columnCfgs: [{
                    text: textExpandCollapse,
                    //icon: '/slm/images/icon_story.gif',  // Use a URL in the icon config
                    width: 50,
                    listeners: {
                        click: {
                        ...
                        ...

groot=this.add(GridComponent);
groot.getView().refresh();
```

Why are we able to call getView() on groot variable? 'groot' variable contains the Ext.Component according to my understanding. And Ext.Component doesnt have getView() method in App SDK 2.0 Docs.
I am trying to understand the framework. Please lemme know if i am understanding it wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *groot* variable contains a component of xtype 'rallygrid', which I guess is a *grid*. So yes, the grid is a descendent of Ext.Component, but has some methods of its own, and in particular, the "getView" method.

Comment: ah... yea. I saw the hierarchy. Thanks!